# type object 'x' has no attribute filter

Tags: python, sql, django

I am using python to get values from one of table using filter .

```
queryset1 = model_user_profile.UserProfile.filter(user = uid).values('time_zone')
```

where model_user_table has following columns:

```
---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id            | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_id       | int(11)      | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| time_zone     | varchar(128) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

value of uid and user_id in above query and table respectively are 1 and 1 , but still query fails and `error: AttributeError: type object 'UserProfile' has no attribute 'filter'` is displayed.

I am using similar queries in past but never received such error , what can be the possible issue????

Comment: `UserProfile.objects.filter`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this:

filter is like where clause in sql

```
obj = your_model.objects.filter( user = uid)
```

for more info see this [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/)